# convert values from one coordinate system (x,y) to another coordinate system (x', y')

Tags: matrices, transformation, coordinate-systems

Following is a graph that contains both coordinate systems (x,y) and (x',y'). x, y, x', and y' are all axes

```
y'
^
|
+----------> x
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+-> x'
|
v
y
```

Above is a picture of a graph. For example, the following is graph or grid of the (x',y') coordinate system.

```
y'
^
|
+--------+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+-> x'
```

What is the transformation T which transforms coordinates (x,y) to coordinates (x',y')? Please include simple, intuitive explanations and steps. Note: the solution, T, is probably a 2d matrix.

Comment: Your $x'$ is the same as your old $x$. Your $y'$ is $3-y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your $x'$ is the same as your $x$. To get $y'$, first note that $y$ is in the opposite direction of $y'$. Hence, $y = c - y'$ where $c$ is some constant. The constant is obtained by finding the value of $y$ at say $y'=0$, in your case the constant is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you will have $x=x'$ and $y=3-y'$.

The solution is not going to be a matrix, because the transformation is not linear.  Linear transformations always preserve the origin of the coordinate system, and in your diagram the origin for the $x$-$y$ axes is in a different place than the origin for the $x'$-$y'$ axes.